# Azure ARM template how to use copy for multiple parts

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-rm-template

I have a problem I can't find a solution for, it's when I try to use copy to create multiple parts dynamically in my dashboard ARM template.

I get the error when I try to use "[copyIndex()]" in one of the keys, as I understand from the error message this will not work. But I'm not sure how I can get around the issue, so any ideas would be appreciated.

```
"copy": [
  {
    "name": "servers",
    "count": "[length(parameters('locationKeys'))]",
    "input": {
      "[copyIndex('servers')]": {
        "position": {
          "x": "[mul(copyIndex('servers'), 4)]",
          "y": 1,
          "colSpan": 2,
          "rowSpan": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

As you can see in the example above this is what fails

```
"[copyIndex('servers')]": {
```

And I get this error

```
Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 
'Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.'.
```

The structure to create the dashboard looks like this

```
"properties": {
  "lenses": {
    "0": {
      "order": 0,
      "parts": {
        "0": {},
        "1": {},
        ...
```

And I have the copy function under the "parts" key.

The way around this would be to remove the copy function and duplicate the code, but then I have a hard time to get it to work with any given number of "locations" since I need to hard code them.

Basically this is what I want to get in the end.

[image]

Are there any other good solutions to get around this problem?

**UPDATE**

These are the two templates I reference from my Azure DevOps task in the pipeline. Note that I now need to do parameters('locationKeys')[0] and duplicate all the blocks instead of doing a copy with parameters('locationKeys')[copyIndex()].

parameters.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "locationNames": {
      "value": "#{locationNames}"
    }
  }
}
```

deploy.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "appName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue" : "myApp"
    },
    "locationNames": {
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "dashboardName": "[concat(parameters('appName'), '-dashboard')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[variables('dashboardName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Portal/dashboards",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01-preview",
      "location": "westeurope",
      "tags": {
        "hidden-title": "24/7 Operations"
      },
      "properties": {
        "lenses": {
          "0": {
            "order": 0,
            "parts": {
              "0": {
                "position": {
                  "x": 0,
                  "y": 0,
                  "colSpan": 4,
                  "rowSpan": 1
                },
                "metadata": {
                  "inputs": [],
                  "type": "Extension/HubsExtension/PartType/MarkdownPart",
                  "settings": {
                    "content": {
                      "settings": {
                        "content": "[concat('# ', parameters('locationNames')[0])]",
                        "title": "",
                        "subtitle": ""
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "1": {
                "position": {
                  "x": 4,
                  "y": 0,
                  "colSpan": 4,
                  "rowSpan": 1
                },
                "metadata": {
                  "inputs": [],
                  "type": "Extension/HubsExtension/PartType/MarkdownPart",
                  "settings": {
                    "content": {
                      "settings": {
                        "content": "[concat('# ', parameters('locationNames')[1])]",
                        "title": "",
                        "subtitle": ""
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "2": {
                "position": {
                  "x": 8,
                  "y": 0,
                  "colSpan": 4,
                  "rowSpan": 1
                },
                "metadata": {
                  "inputs": [],
                  "type": "Extension/HubsExtension/PartType/MarkdownPart",
                  "settings": {
                    "content": {
                      "settings": {
                        "content": "[concat('# ', parameters('locationNames')[2])]",
                        "title": "",
                        "subtitle": ""
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": []
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "resourceGroupId": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[resourceGroup().id]"
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is the working example with objects instead of an array. I verified it locally with PowerShell by uploading the collector.json and transform.json to http://myjson.com and include them as properties when running the deploy.

parameters.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "azureEnvironment": {
      "value": "#{azureEnvironment}"
    },
    "locationKeys": {
      "value": "#{locationKeys}"
    },
    "locationNames": {
      "value": "#{locationNames}"
    },
    "transformTemplateLink": {
      "value": "#{transform}"
    },
    "collectorTemplateLink": {
      "value": "#{collector}"
    }
  }
}
```

deploy.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "appName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "myApp"
    },
    "azureEnvironment": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "locationKeys": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "locationNames": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "transformTemplateLink": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[uri(deployment().properties.templateLink.uri, 'transform.json')]"
    },
    "collectorTemplateLink": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[uri(deployment().properties.templateLink.uri, 'collector.json')]"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
      "name": "collector",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[parameters('collectorTemplateLink')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "transformTemplateUri": {
            "value": "[parameters('transformTemplateLink')]"
          },
          "locationNames": {
            "value": "[parameters('locationNames')]"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('appName'), '-dash-', parameters('azureEnvironment'))]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Portal/dashboards",
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01-preview",
      "location": "westeurope",
      "tags": {
        "hidden-title": "[concat('24/7 Operations - (', parameters('azureEnvironment'), ')')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "lenses": {
          "0": {
            "order": 0,
            "parts": "[reference('collector').outputs.result.value]"
          }
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "collector"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "resourceGroupId": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[resourceGroup().id]"
    }
  }
}
```

collector.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "transformTemplateUri": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "locationNames": {
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "count": "[length(parameters('locationNames'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
      "name": "loop-0",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "parameters": {},
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "parameters": {},
          "variables": {},
          "resources": [],
          "outputs": {
            "collection": {
              "type": "object",
              "value": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
      "name": "[concat('loop-', copyIndex(1))]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "iterator",
        "count": "[variables('count')]",
        "mode": "serial"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('loop-', copyIndex())]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[parameters('transformTemplateUri')]"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "state": {
            "value": "[reference(concat('loop-', copyIndex())).outputs.collection.value]"
          },
          "index": {
            "value": "[copyIndex()]"
          },
          "locationNames": {
            "value": "[parameters('locationNames')]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "result": {
      "type": "object",
      "value": "[reference(concat('loop-', variables('count'))).outputs.collection.value]"
    }
  }
}
```

transform.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "state": {
      "type": "object",
      "defaultValue": {}
    },
    "index": {
      "type": "int"
    },
    "locationNames": {
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "instance": {
      "[string(parameters('index'))]": {
        "position": {
          "x": "[mul(parameters('index'), 4)]",
          "y": 0,
          "colSpan": 4,
          "rowSpan": 1
        },
        "metadata": {
          "inputs": [],
          "type": "Extension/HubsExtension/PartType/MarkdownPart",
          "settings": {
            "content": {
              "settings": {
                "content": "[concat('# ', parameters('locationNames')[parameters('index')])]",
                "title": "",
                "subtitle": ""
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [],
  "outputs": {
    "collection": {
      "type": "object",
      "value": "[union(parameters('state'), variables('instance'))]"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you just try the same (but simplified) approach in the variables section you would get this error:

> The variable name cannot be an expression.

I think the same applies everywhere, you cant use expression to calculate property name, only value. having said that, if you want to create a loop you'd need to use nested deployment as an iterator. you will pass needed pieces inside\assemble them there based on input and create a resulting array:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "variables": {
        "locations": [
            "eastus",
            "westeurope"
        ],
        "eastus": {
            "red": 1
        },
        "westeurope": {
            "blue": 2
        },
        "empty": []
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
            "name": "[concat('iterator-', copyIndex(1))]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "copy": {
                "name": "someName",
                "count": "[length(variables('locations'))]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                    "uri": "https://paste.ee/r/t5ca9/0"
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "source": {
                        "value": "[variables(variables('locations')[copyIndex()])]"
                    },
                    "state": {
                        "value": "[if(equals(copyIndex(), 0), variables('empty'), reference(concat('iterator-', copyIndex())).outputs.collection.value)]"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "results": {
            "type": "array",
            "value": "[reference(concat('iterator-', string(length(variables('locations'))))).outputs.collection.value]"
        }
    } }
```

and your iterator looks like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "source": {
            "type": "object"
        },
        "state": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": []
        }
    },
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "collection": {
            "type": "array",
            "value": "[concat(array(parameters('source')), parameters('state'))]"
        }
    }
}
```

ps. that link is temporary (1 month), but you can upload the iterator template anywhere and just hardcode, it contains no secrets\no data.
pps. easier way - construct this outside the template (powershell\python\whatever) and pass as a parameter inside the tempate

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll have a look and see if I can get it to work for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: this is what I've been using to create arrays for a very long time, so it will work, just have to conceptualize it in your head ;)

Comment: I must admit I have some difficulties understanding how I should put it together, especially in my case that I showed you above in the question. The only dynamic value is the array of locations, ["location 1", "location 2", "location 3"]. From that I want to get an object with some values with the copyIndex() as keys for each entry.
As I understand all of it goes into the deploymentTemplate, so I should manage by just one file for my simple example, correct?
Do you have some more complete example I can have a look at?

Comment: Or is "uri": "someUri" the link to the deploymentTemplate to use for that section?

Comment: yes, its the link to the nested template (third json snippet) you need to use. nested templates have to be uploaded somewhere. tell me if you need more complete example? i'll get back to you some time today

Comment: Ok, at the moment I use the "Azure Resource Group Deployment" task in my Azure DevOps pipeline. In that task I need to enter the "Template" uri and a "Template paramters" uri in my repository. Will I still need to link the deploymentTemplate there, or should I link to the template in your first snippet where I add all nested deployment parameters which then calls the final deploymentTemplate?

Comment: If you have some time to show me an example of the files and their content I need to setup my example above I can probably manage to handle the rest from there. I will add an update in my question with the files and content I have as of now.

Comment: ok, provided a working example. you can make it more sophisticated, by offloading some logic to the nested template, right now all the logic is in the main template

Comment: Is this a typo? "name": "[concat('iterator-', copyIndex(1))]", was thinking about the 1 in the copyIndex?

Comment: no, this is not a typo, this has to be like this due to how reference works

Comment: Ok, I understand how your example works now and how it will output an object with  {"eastus": {"red": 1}, "westeurope": {"blue": 2}}. But not sure how to solve my problem where I want it fully dynamically. Especially how to iterate and populate the "parts" object (in my updated example) with with all the objects for the given regions in my locationNames array. Can I use a reference to the file I have created? https://paste.ee/p/oXvAK, does this look correct?

Comment: reference it from inside the "parts" object in my example above*

Comment: it's a bit hard to grasp it, but you will just do this: `"parts" : "[reference(result_goes_here)"]`.so you construct needed array and then just plug it in where you need it. your example looks fine

Comment: Is it correct that the "empty": [] variable is the starting point of the iteration, we start with an empty array and then add to that and that copyIndex() always refers to the last iteration?

Comment: more or less. to better understand what is going on go to the resource group and examine iterator deployments input and output

Comment: Omg, this works perfectly. I understand what it does and how it works, but how on earth did you come up with this solution/workaround?

Comment: well, back in the days I needed an array and I had to come up with something. this is the result of that struggle...

Answer (score 1):

OMG!
fell into exact same trap!
like in the very first example the copy index should work!

> "[copyIndex('servers')]": {

at least after reading the copyIndex documentation that's what my assumption was!
after seeing this post I tried to do it in the same way! but I pretty much spent half a day! really felt creating your own JSON(ARM Template) using PowerShell
would have saved my time!

```
$header = @'
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"resources": [
{
"properties": {
"lenses": {
"0": {
"order": 0,
"parts": {
'@
$footer =     @"
}}}},
    "name": "$($resourceGroupName)",
    "type": "Microsoft.Portal/dashboards",
    "location": "$($Location)",
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01-preview"
    }]
}
"@
$parts  = ""
for ($i = 0; $i -le $Totalplans; $i++)
{
$parts += @"
            "$($i)": {
              "position": {
                "x": $($xIndex[$i]),
                "y": $($yIndex[$i]),
                "colSpan": 4,
                "rowSpan": 4
              },
              "metadata": {
                "inputs": [
                  {
                    "name": "sharedTimeRange",
                    "isOptional": true
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "options",
                    "value": {
                      "chart": {
                        "metrics": [
                          {
                            "resourceMetadata": {
                              "id": "$($ResourceIDs[$i])"
                            },
                            "name": "$($name[$i])",
                            "aggregationType": 4,
                            "namespace": "microsoft.web/serverfarms",
                            "metricVisualization": {
                              "displayName":"$($title[$i])",
                              "resourceDisplayName": "$($ResourceNames[$i])"
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "title":"$($title[$i])",
                        "titleKind": 2,
                        "visualization": {
                          "chartType": 2,
                          "legendVisualization": {
                            "isVisible": true,
                            "position": 2,
                            "hideSubtitle": false
                          },
                          "axisVisualization": {
                            "x": {
                              "isVisible": true,
                              "axisType": 2
                            },
                            "y": {
                              "isVisible": true,
                              "axisType": 1
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "timespan": {
                          "relative": {
                            "duration": 3600000
                          },
                          "showUTCTime": false,
                          "grain": 2
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "isOptional": true
                  }
                ],
                "type": "Extension/HubsExtension/PartType/MonitorChartPart",
                "settings": {
                  "content": {
                    "options": {
                      "chart": {
                        "metrics": [
                          {
                            "resourceMetadata": {
                              "id":  "$($ResourceIDs[$i])"
                            },
                            "name": "$($name[$i])",
                            "aggregationType": 4,
                            "namespace": "microsoft.web/serverfarms",
                            "metricVisualization": {
                              "displayName":"$($title[$i])",
                              "resourceDisplayName":"$($ResourceNames[$i])"
                            }
                          }
                        ],
                        "title": "$($title[$i])",
                        "titleKind": 2,
                        "visualization": {
                          "chartType": 2,
                          "legendVisualization": {
                            "isVisible": true,
                            "position": 2,
                            "hideSubtitle": false
                          },
                          "axisVisualization": {
                            "x": {
                              "isVisible": true,
                              "axisType": 2
                            },
                            "y": {
                              "isVisible": true,
                              "axisType": 1
                            }
                          },
                          "disablePinning": true
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "filters": {
                  "MsPortalFx_TimeRange": {
                    "model": {
                      "format": "local",
                      "granularity": "1m",
                      "relative": "60m"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
"@
}


$parts = $parts.Substring(0,$parts.Length-1)



Remove-Item "template.json" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

"$($header)$($parts)$($footer)" >> "template.json"
```

I know this is raw but the above-mentioned workaround is also not a proper way anyway!